# Localhost not found after migrating application from .net 5 to .net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller, localhost

I am unable to run my web application project in IIS Express after migrating from .net 5 to .net 6. I get an error stating that "the localhost page can't be found."

From what I've been able to learn, I have gone through the proper steps to migrate between target frameworks. I have changed the target framework to .net 6 in application properties, and I have updated all affected NuGet packages using the NuGet Pkg Manager. No errors are shown when I build the project, and I have ensured Visual Studio is updated to the latest version, 17.2.5 as of this writing.

The IIS Settings in my launchsettings.json file are as follows:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:35317",
      "sslPort": 44352
    }
  }
```

and I do have an Index view return in my home controller. Yet I still get the error that

```
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44352/
```

when I run the application.

I am retaining the "old" hosting model of Startup.cs and Program.cs from the .Net 5 build to save time, as I understand per Microsoft that this is acceptable. No changes have been made to the code in either of those files.

What am I missing?

EDIT: My Program.cs code is below, by request of @adrianMoskal

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Per @adrianMoskal, I updated my Program.cs file to .NET 6 standard. It now looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add DB Contexts and Services here

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Unfortunately, the error persists.

Comment: Check your `applicationHost.config` file (it'll be under your `.vs` directory) - try deleting it and restarting VS.

Comment: @Dai Unfortunately, I have no such file in this project. No .vs directory, either. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: I doubt that given that you can't run IIS Express without `applicationHost.config` in the first place: I can assure you _the file exists_ somewhere in your solution directory tree, you just need to find it. Check you can see Hidden Files and Folders in Explorer, and use a tool like VoidTools Everything to find the file on-disk. (It is not a project-file btw)

Comment: Can you show your Program.cs content?

Comment: @Dai Yeah, it was a hidden file. Sorry about that. I found the one for my project, deleted it, and restarted VS. Unfortunately, no change.

Comment: @adrianMoskal Program.cs code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be "screw you, start over."

I've tried copying my project code to a new .net 6 project -- that is, copying all the views, controllers, and whatnot to the new project and updating the new Program.cs file accordingly -- and I still got the same error. I then tried converting a different .net 5 project to .net 6, and got the same error again. So apparently, converting just doesn't work.

So be it. I quit. I've got too much else to do to worry about this. Thanks to those who responded to this post for trying to help resolve it, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project to migrate from .net 5 to .net 6, but no problem, it works fine, I will show you the complete steps：

.csproj:

change Version like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>-->
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>_2022070802</RootNamespace>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.16" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then I delete Startup.cs and change Program.cs：

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add DB Contexts and Services here

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

More detail information, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

You can create a new empty project to migrate from .net 5 to .net 6 and see if the problem still exists.I think this may be the problem caused by some of your configuration, maybe you can check whether your path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Chen's answer is the correct migration step.

I tried to reproduce your issue. When I comment Index page method in HomeController. And I face the same issue.

**So you probably deleted your "Index" action in HomeController.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: nope, my Index action is present and correct, no comments or anything. Now, I did have it set as an async Task, so I stripped that stuff out and ran it as a standard Action, and no change.